# Jquery wrapping poorly formatted HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I have some extremely poorly formatted HTML code, where each element in a table is a row. I want to group the sub-elements a little easier, by adding some HTML to the page.  Here is a small example of the HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table width="100%">
      <tr class="heading">
        <td>value 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>sub 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>sub 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="heading">
        <td>value 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>sub 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="heading">
        <td>value 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>sub 3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>​
```

I'd like to wrap each of the rows with a class of heading, with another tr or div or really anything to allow me to grab the sub-elements a bit easier. I've tried various combinations of before, html, etc.. yet I can't seem to get this to work.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XPNFf/) that I've put together. Any way to wrap the the tr values with a class of heading? For example, I'd like to grab the 3 rows with class heading in the sample HTML. I'd like to prepend that first row with some HTML, and close it before the start of the second row. I would repeat that process for each row (open a tag and close it before the next row), on the final row I would simply close it.

So the output I would like is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table width="100%">
      <SOME_TAG>
        <tr class="heading">
          <td>value 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sub 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sub 1</td>
        </tr>
      </SOME_TAG>
      <SOME_TAG>
        <tr class="heading">
          <td>value 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sub 2</td>
        </tr>
      </SOME_TAG>
      <SOME_TAG>
        <tr class="heading">
          <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sub 3</td>
        </tr>
      </SOME_TAG>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>​
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? You cannot wrap `TR` with a `DIV`. A `TR` can be wrapped inside a `THEAD`/`TBODY`/`TFOOT`. Tell us what you are trying to do.. and which sub-elements you are trying to access?

Comment: I can't figure out how this would make your life easier. Why not just use `tr.heading:eq(0)`, `tr.heading:eq(1)` and then use sibling selectors? I suspect the answer is to learn the full range of jQuery's selectors, not munge up your HTML with a bunch of useless wrapper classes.

Comment: I'm using selenium to basically parse this page and grab information about each of the elements. To reliably do that, I need to add this information to make it "parseable", otherwise the logic becomes quite dirty to figure out when I've moved onto the next element.

Comment: You cannot have `<SOMETAG>` wrapping a `TR`.. A TR can be wrapped inside a THEAD/TBODY/TFOOT. It is an invalid HTML.

Comment: @Vega I was stating that I don't care what tag is used, not that I wanted that explicitly.

Comment: How about i return you a group of tr that is under each header.. will that work?

Comment: @Vega that would allow us to easily parse as well. I need to make the initial statment from the $("tr.heading") element.

Comment: I take it you don't have access to the source HTML to change it.  Would it be acceptable to use JQuery to replace the table-related elements to other types of elements, such as DIV, that might be easier to work with for your purposes?

Comment: @vertigoelectric That is correct, we do not have access to modify the HTML output, it's a third party system.

Comment: What if your <SOME_TAG> is a set of tags.. would that work ? say <tr><td><table class="usefulGrouping"> and the end tag </SOME_TAG> can be </table></td></tr>

Comment: That would work as well ksskr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on kssr's suggestion — wrap them in subtables using nextUntil and wrapAll

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        wrapTR(0);
    });

    function wrapTR(index)
    {
        $('tr.heading:eq('+index+')').nextUntil('.heading').andSelf().wrapAll('<table class="useful-grouping" id="table-'+index+'"/>');
        if($('tr.heading:eq('+index+')').next('.heading'))
        {
            wrapTR(index+1)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Works perfectly on the fiddle. Unfortunately when utilizing this on the real page, we receive a maximum call stack error, but this worked perfectly on the fiddle. Thanks!